# How do I get my OpenGraph objects to be "liked" properly?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Still more OpenGraph newbie-ism:

I define a page on my site with a full set of metatags appropriate for a "video".  This is a standard OG video; no custom stuff.  All is well; the page passes the object linter successfully, and is identified as a video:movie.  The page also contains a Like button created in the "usual" way -- a div of class "fb-like" with a set of parameters, and some activating javascript.

Joe, a user, goes to the page and clicks the Like button; the following happens:

- The Like overlay box appears, showing the info about the page/object, a textfield for a comment, and a Post button.
- The Like counter on the button is incremented.
- But then, the box immediately disappears, without being clicked on and without anything being entered into it.  (There was never really any chance to do so.)
- The Like increment is lost; it goes back to whatever it was before.
- Joe's Facebook profile page contains an entry "Joe likes a link", with a correct depiction of the page/object, including the ability to play the video on the profile page.
- Joe's friends do not get any notification of this liking, although the liking is marked as "public" in Joe's activity log.

Now, I define another page on my site that is virtually the same, but that has only the basic sorts of metatags, enough to get it identified as an OG 'website'.  Again, the linter is happy.  Joe now goes to this page and clicks the Like button.  This time, the behavior is correct, or at least what I expect:

- The Like counter is incremented.
- The overlay box appears and stays up for Joe to enter something.  He does so, and clicks the Post button.
- The Like counter retains its newly-incremented button.
- Joe's FB profile page contains an entry with his name, the comment he entered into the "like" box, and a depiction of the page/object. This can't be played as a video, since OG doesn't know it's a video.  Note, btw, that the entry is made up of only Joe's name, not "Joe likes a link" as in the other case.
- Joe's friends get an entry in their feed -- the same thing as appears on Joe's profile page.

I'm pretty baffled by this behavior -- I'd like to have the pages represented as OG videos for a variety of reasons, but the Liking behavior just isn't working.  Has anybody seen anything comparable?  Any advice out there??

Comment: Closing this for now; unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug, perhaps you should enter it in the bug tracker tool at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Comment: That was certainly my thought, but I'm pretty new to OG, so I thought I'd look around for some other opinions.  It's been awhile, so it's off to the bug tracker...

Comment: Hmm: Just found this as a "trending bug": https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254250354686066 .  It's not quite the same, but might be related.  I've filed the above behavior as a new bug; we'll see...